# Fontawesome loading but not displaying properly Play Framework Firefox

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework-2.0, font-awesome

To start, I am new to Play framework and Scala, but not Java. I have confirmed that this is not an issue in Google Chrome. first just tried copy-pasting the cdn, then realized I needed to serve the actual fonts, so I cloned from FontAwesome's repo. Below are the directory tree and the cdn version as a working snippet. I have read about CORS issues but I wouldn't expect that to be an issue while running tests locally. The `HTML` is the same (I left out some directories from the tree to so make this more concise):

```
   |
   |--app
   |   |
   |   |--controllers
   |   |--filters
   |   |--services
   |   |--views
   |
   |--public
   |    |
   |    |--fontAwesome
   |    |       |
   |    |       |--css
   |    |       |
   |    |       |-webfonts
   |    |
   |    |--stylesheets
   |    |
   |    |--javascripts
   |    |
   |    |--images  
   |
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 dev-box">
        <a href="https://github.com/HarryCaveMan" target="_blank" class="pro-box github">
        <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>Github</a>
</div>
```

In the `main.scala.html` layout,  I link the fontawesome `css` file with the router as follows:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("fontAwesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css")">
```

Which is the same way I did it for every other stylesheet and it worked fine (and I can see it load in the network tab of dev tools), Except all I get is the little unicode box for `"\f09b"`. Also, both show the same `content:"\f09b";` style rule in the dev tools, but only the Play version doesn't display properly (it does display, just wrong). As always, thanks for any help!